# ANSYS: how to organize my code?

Tags: simulation

I'm using ANSYS to analyse a basic structure, and I need to switch between dynamic analysis, static analysis. And sometimes I need to only consider a certain load. This makes the solution part in a mess.

```
!!! Add wind loads
*DIM,windforce,,4 
windforce(1) = 2520
windforce(2) = -1575
windforce(3) = -1890
windforce(4) = -1575

*DO,i,1,3
SFBEAM,i ,1 ,PRES ,windforce(1)
*enddo
*DO,i,4,6
SFBEAM,i ,1 ,PRES ,windforce(2)
*enddo
*DO,i,7,9
SFBEAM,i ,1 ,PRES ,windforce(3)
*enddo
*DO,i,10,12
SFBEAM,i ,1 ,PRES ,windforce(4)
*enddo



FINISH 
/SOLU                   ! enter solution phase

! !!Dynamic Analysis
! antype,modal                  
! modopt,lanb,40,0,0,,off          
! mxpand,0,,,0                     
! lumpm,1
! solve
! finish

! ! ! Generate Mass and K Matrix
! antype,substr
! seopt,yg_bde,2
! lumpm,1 
! m,all,all      
! /output,matrix
! solve
! /output
! selist,yg_bde,3
! finish

SOLVE                   ! solve the resulting system of equations
FINISH
```

Everytime I swtich between this analysis, I need to comment in/out a big chuck of code. And this looks really terrible.

So How can I organize my code? Or how to make this code modulize? Is there any framework for ANSYS scripting language? (Like `scss` for `css`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is exactly such tool, but there is a [list](http://ansys.net/?mycat=tools) of Ansys approved text editors and other helpful programs (digitizers, CAD converters e.t.c).

I guess, if there will be any good framework, it must be listed there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use chunks of code in separate files and then call on these files in main code.

Simplest way to switch parts of code is to use *IF condition in combination with argument. Then you can call on your script as myscript.txt,ARG1,ARG2,ARG3.. where myscript.txt is your script name (also *.ans,*.mac ...) and ARGx are your switches.

Sample:

```
! here is the same stuff for any run

*IF,ARG1,EQ,1,then
! here is one variation of the code (e.g. static analysis)
*ENDIF

*IF,ARG1,EQ,2,then
! here is another variation of the code (e.g. dynamic analysis)
*ENDIF

! here is again code used for any variation of the code
```

If the sample above is in text file called solverswitch.txt, then you would execute various solver options via solverswitch.txt,1 (or solverswitch.txt,2)

Answer (score 0):

I use **jedit** to edit complex ANSYS files, it recognizes most ANSYS commands and color-codes them for easy reference, besides having various typical functionalities of scripting software.

You have to rename your input files *.ans so that jedit recognizes the ANSYS format.

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by "modulize" the code, but you can create various scripts and call them from a main routine with the command
/INPUT,'file_name','file_extension','relative_path',,0

Answer (score 0):

I work mainly with bridges and I frequently have to do multiple types of analyses (static, dynamic, etc.). My workflow is a base APDL file, e.g. "truss_bridge.txt" which calls other files: "bridge_load.txt", "bridge_design.txt", "bridge_out.txt" for different types of analyses, meshing, outputs, respectively.
I separate these different options inside of each file with the /EOF command and call the type of analysis that I want with the /INPUT command specifying the appropriate line. So my base file for your situation could be something like:

```
  /INPUT,viaduct_materials,txt,direct      ! material parameters
  /INPUT,viaduct_real_constants,txt,direct ! R.C. parameters    
  /INPUT,viaduct_design,txt,direct         ! Design bridge and meshing

  /INPUT,viaduct_load,txt,direct,1 ! LOAD File static analysis
  ! Post Processing
  /INPUT,viaduct_out,txt,direct,1 ! Output file  S.A.

  /INPUT,viaduct_load,txt,direct,14 ! LOAD File dynamic analysis
  ! Post Processing
  /INPUT,viaduct_out,txt,direct,21 ! Output file  D.A.
```